# How to add the service and Observable catch for this charts(live Data).?

Tags: angular, highcharts

[live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lj5p84pr9) I need to add the service and Observable catch  for this charts because the chart is live data and I find a problem where the browser is blocking, the api time-rows.json continue running in console log(network).

[image]

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
declare var require: any;
require("highcharts/modules/data")(Highcharts);

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        type: "spline"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Live Data (Rows JSON)"
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: "Data input from a remote JSON file"
      },

      data: {
        rowsURL: "https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-rows.json",
        firstRowAsNames: false,
        enablePolling: true
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

```html
<div
  id="container"
  style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"
></div>
```

Comment: The live demo doesn't have any observable, could you reproduce your issue more precisely? Perhaps this demo will help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v3vk58o7

Comment: Hi @WojciechChmiel, I work with same chart (live data) but I have a problem when I open new page the API "https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-rows.json" continue runningin in console(network).After time period the browser block.what is the solution!!!!

Comment: Perhaps you should use another approach of updating a chart with live data. Make a service where data will be fetched from the server, then send an observable or default events with new data and add it to chartOptions. Once again I encourage you to check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v3vk58o7 (instead of setTimeout you should fetch data from a server). `data.enablePolling` property is not designed to work with modern js frameworks like Angular.